# How do I change my Stack Overflow profile picture?

Tags: support, profile-page, gravatar

I want to change my Stack Overflow picture, but when I click 'edit' in my profile page and then 'change picture', I'm taken to some stupid Gravatar web site... I really don't want the Gravatar!

Comment: It's either gravatar or geometry picture, sorry pal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's tied to the [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) that your Email address uses.

- Go to Gravatar.com
- create a profile and upload a picture.
- Add that Email address to your Stack Overflow profile.
- Wait a few hours for it to propogate.

[This question has been asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/non-gravatar-avatar), and is as of 2017 is: `[status-completed]`!

You may now use [this method](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/01/15/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/) to update your profile picture.

Comment: George, what if I don't want to use a gravatar? I get REALLY frustrated when I am FORCED to use another service which I'm not really interested in... gravatar is such a service.  Is there anything else I can do to change the picture?

Comment: No. Those are the breaks. However, there is a duplicate question out there that says this is 'deferred'. :-)

Comment: @Lirik: Then you are stuck with the default avatar. SO uses gravatar as their avatar service.

Comment: @George unfortunately I can't mark your answer as "accepted", because my stackoverflow profile does not display any answers under this question and my meta.stackoverflow profile is not associated with this profile.  How can I accept your answer?

Comment: @Lirik You can associate your accounts and then accept answers. To associate your accounts, click your name at the top of the page, then click on the `Accounts` tab.

Comment: OpenID and Gravatar are modern ways to remove the need to create/duplicate new profiles/avatars again and again on every site/forum/board the world wide web is aware of. Maybe you don't see any benefit of it yet. Just register once and don't worry. It costs less time than you wasted in posting this question ;)

Comment: Did you see the Gravatar introductory video? I do not want to create a Gravatar and share all that personal information with who-knows-who. If you say that I should not put there what I do not want to share, then what's the point of a Gravatar, anyway? All I want to share is my picture with StackOverflow members. Is that too difficult to allow?

Comment: George i did what u had said, created a profile on Gravatar, but nothing happened, my profile picture did get changed !

Comment: That same happened to me, i created my gravatar profile but didn't get my profile oic changed...