# How to change to SO profile image if you’re using OpenID for login?

Tags: discussion, support, openid, gravatar, profile-page

Im logged in using my OpenID but profile images appear to be connected to Gravatar only?

Comment: @dmckee: it'd be nice if those people would take the time to state that.  "this belongs on... ...and will be *sent there automatically*, please don't crosspost".

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, gravatar is the only option. Is there some reason it doesn't work as an option for you? You can add many email addresses and many pictures to your gravatar account, so as to not overlap various types of profile pictures with various types of websites that use gravatar.

Comment: Thanks for watching my bad, Downvoter!

Comment: I dont remember what email address I used when I signed up for OpenID and logging into my OpenID page didn't show me anything in the profile. I do have Gravatar login but I guess I have to find the email address and associate an image with it for it to show up.

Comment: The email address it uses is the one listed in your StackOverflow profile (or other site)

Comment: I found my email settings in my OpenID page and Ill be adding that address to my Gravatar profile shortly. Thanks.

Comment: @Eno, no! Like Chacha102 wrote: it's the address on your Stack Overflow profile, and is not related to your OpenID profile at all. Remember that OpenID did not ask you to share any personal information with this site when logging in the first time? All personal information is at your Stack Overflow profile.

Comment: Indeed, Gravatar is the only option, and that's not likely to change soon; see the *deferred* "non-gravatar avatar?" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/non-gravatar-avatar

Comment: The weird thing is, my email address in my SO profile is *already* associated with an image at Gravatar. But I dont see any custom image...

Comment: Still not seeing my Gravatar...

Answer (score 1):

The avatar used on your stackexchange accounts does not necessarily correspond to your login method.  Rather, it is pulled from gravatar.com according to the email address in your account on each stackexchange site.

In my case, I use MyOpenID.com to log into stackexchange sites, and my MyOpenID profile does not contain my email address, but I was able to make my gravatar show up on stackexchange.  Here's how.
On each stackexchange site where your gravatar doesn't show up (eg, meta.stackoverflow.com, etc.):

1. Click your username at the top, to get to your account page
2. Click 'edit' to enter your email address*
3. If you don't yet have any gravatar associated with this email address*, add this email address to gravatar.com and associate an image with it

Note: * You don't have to use your 'best' email address.  Since it is only used for the gravatar, you can use any email address you want, or even a throwaway address such as from mailinator.com.  However, you do have to check the email address once for the confirmation email from gravatar.com.