# How can I manage my questions asked before I'm registered?

Tags: support, questions, unregistered-users

I can't edit or comment now. I guess it's because I changed my computer.
How can I get back the control again?

Answer (score 2):

If you have links to the questions then flag one of them (assuming they're all linked to the same account) and ask a moderator to merge that account with your registered one.

Or email "team@stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Thanks. I can find the question by tag. But how can I talk to a moderator (or anyone)? It seems there's no messaging system in these sites.

Comment: @phoenies - flag one of the questions for moderator attention. That's the one link that exists on all posts regardless of how much or how little reputation you have.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the archives: given that accounts are now [associated automatically](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/), I guess it's no longer an issue for those who're smart enough to use the same OpenID to log in.

Or, even when not registered, there's an option to get the cookie back<sup>†</sup> using the account recovery, through the [Forgot your login information?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) link.

<sup><sup>†</sup> See Jeff's comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You need to login with the same account as you did before changing computer.

Comment: I didn't login with any account before changing computer. I wasn't registered.

Comment: @phoenies - associate your Stack Overflow and meta account to regain ownership of *this* question. It's the rightmost tab on your profile page.