# Unregistered users should be able to delete their own answers

Tags: support, status-bydesign, answers, unregistered-users, self-delete

I used to think that all users can delete their own posts, as long as these posts haven't gained a relevant number of upvotes. After seeing posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593294/wpfitemscontrol-not-completely-loaded-loaded-event/2847725#2847725) again and again, I decided to verify my assumption and found out that you actually *can't* delete your own answers if you post from a low reputation, cookie based account.

Is there a reason for this or is this unintentional?

In my opinion even users without a "substantial" account should be able to change their minds and delete an answer if they think better of it.

Comment: +1 - I agree.  Can I delete that answer now?  It's bothering me.

Answer (score 14):

This is by-design.

If you want to delete posts (remember, a delete is considered a *vote*) then you have to use a **registered** account.

Cookie-based accounts don't support voting, therefore they don't support deletion.

So if you want to nag the user to register so he or she can delete their own stuff, feel free to do so.