# Logged in users with less than 15 reputation should be able to give feedback

Tags: feature-request, voting, up-votes, feedback

If I'm not logged in to any Stack Exchange site, I can give feedback clicking on vote button:

> [image]

But if I'm logged in, and I have less than 15 reputation, I get a message that more reputation is required:

> [image]

All I can do is to log out and give feedback.

But for me this is not logical. If someone does not have not enough reputation, he/she should be treated as unregistered one, being given possibility to send feedback instead.

Comment: Proper behavior in my opinion is having the upvote send automatic feedback and say something like "thanks for your feedback, to cast a real upvote you need to earn 15 reputation"

Comment: Or as they shall be known from now on: "I can't believe these aren't real upvotes" @ShaWizDowArd...

Comment: I tried to log out and cast an upvote. I got asked to log in and no upvote got registered... Can you post a screenshots of actually upvoting question as logged out user? I never seen it possible, so I'm just curious. If it's possible I'd love to see it on drupal.stackexchange.com so I can inspect actual +/- vote count. Feel free to downvote one of my [positively voted question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75370/how-to-combine-views-exposed-filter-with-search) as anonymous, that way you will not hurt anyway and it will not be considered gaming the system.

Comment: @Molot it's not making any upvote just something known as "feedback". In the past there used to be link below each post "this post was helpful" that did it, but the team decided to move its functionality to the vote up button.

Comment: @Bart FYI adding dots after the name (`@namehere....`) "ruins" the notification, I didn't get one for your second comment. I think it allows one dot though.

Comment: "If I'm not logged in to any Stack Exchange site, I can give feedback clicking on vote button."

Comment: Either case does not make sense, so unregister user has more power than a registered one.

Comment: `Either case does not make sense, so unregister user has more power than a registered one` I'm pretty sure that's *exactly* what this question is pointing out...

Answer (score -6):

When you are clicking for example "UP VOTE BUTTON" being not logged in, your vote isn't added publicly, but users reputation higher than 10 K are seeing your feedback.

If you want truly vote, you have to have an account (and be logged to it) with reputation higher than 15 (to upvoting) or 125 (to downvoting).

It isn't illogical, but I think that content of the message should be changed, because current isn't entirely clear.

Comment: This answer is wrong - the feedback *is* added - just through anonymous feedback visible in the 10k tools. -1

Comment: **I improved my answer**

Comment: Now it's not even an answer - you're just repeating the question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, are you sure unregistered users can vote? In 2010 Jeff [wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50260/new-unregistered-users-should-be-able-to-delete-their-own-answers/50271#50271) *"Cookie-based accounts don't support voting, therefore they don't support deletion"*. Also [Why should I register my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) claims *"You will also be completely unable to vote, with the sole exception of accepting answers to your questions"*.

Comment: (hmm, @Sha, so how do you keep that unregistered sockpuppet of yours logged in? `;-)`)

Comment: @Arjan oh my, thanks for the heads up need to learn to check before posting such things. No unregistered sockpuppet, I looked for [dan](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&q=site:stackoverflow.com%2Fusers+%22dan%22+unregistered&oq=site:stackoverflow.com%2Fusers+%22dan%22+unregistered), jon and mike and found many high rep unregistered users without a single vote. Proof enough for me that I was wrong. :)