# Add the fact that only registered users can delete their own questions to our help pages

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, help-center-proposed

This request comes from the post [Why can't a user delete their own question that was just asked and has had no activity?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13683/291924)

The answer to that question was that the user who posted the question was not registered.

However, this information is missing from the [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) section of our help pages.

I suggest the following change to the existing text. The changed text is in bold.

> [**Registered users**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - has only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes
> - has no bounties that were awarded to any answer that isn't already deleted
>
> Simply click the delete link underneath the question.

The **Registered users** text should link to the [How do I create an account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) section. (I am assuming that creating an account is the same thing as registering.)

Adding this information to our help pages could offset some dissatisfaction and churn when some people can't delete their own questions, and others try to help them understand why they can't.

---

Note some posts related to (but not the same as) this request:

- [Unregistered users should be able to delete their own answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50260/389569)
- [Allow unregistered accounts to delete their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273440/389569)