# An unregistered low-rep user was able to delete own post and repost it as a comment on other's question

Tags: support, unregistered-users

This [unregistered user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587657/olga-w) was able to [delete own post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139032/how-to-remove-text-cursor-in-richcombobox-in-richfaces/4783386#4783386) (I thought only registered users were able to) and repost it as [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139032/how-to-remove-text-cursor-in-richcombobox-in-richfaces/#comment-5297366) on a question which is not their own (as per the FAQ it would require 50 rep).

How was that possible? Or are moderators (since shortly?) able to impersonate an user?

Comment: Huh, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3139032/timeline? Hmm.. `<marquee>test</marquee>`

Comment: The FAQ seems to confirm the note about deletion: [Why should I register my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562): *"the site prevents unregistered users from deleting their own posts"*.

Comment: For ones who wonder about my 1st comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76188/marqueexss-hole-in-timeline-page-marquee-comments-are-not-html-xml-escaped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators [have the ability to convert answers into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments/74160#74160). If a non-answer is sufficiently useful that it wouldn't be a bad idea to retain, we can use it to preserve the content in this manner. Accompanying comments may optionally be brought along with it.