# <marquee>XSS hole in timeline page</marquee> - comments are not HTML/XML escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, xss

See for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/76186/timeline) (marquee) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3139032/timeline) (input and select).

For historical reasons, here's a screen of the last one ;)

---

[image]

---

#### Related bugs:

- [XSS hole in activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73480/marqueexss-hole-in-activity-page-marquee-question-titles-are-not-html-xml-e)

Comment: Haha, wow, I actually find that the [example in your example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3139032/timeline) is a much more amusing illustration of this.

Comment: +1 for marquee demo.

Comment: Nice catch, I was wondering what that was.

Comment: Awww man! I was hoping to keep marquee .. "DO YOUR OWN DARN HOMEWORK ...."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix for this has been checked in.

Comment: Fix confirmed for meta. Not for SO yet.

Comment: Fix confirmed for SO as well. Well done, includes markdown as well! :)

Comment: this XSS issue is NOT fixed for *edit* comments. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3122/timeline (introduced by this answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/64962/revisions)

Comment: @Arjan - a fix for that has been checked in.  Thanks for the report.