# XSS security problems

Tags: bug, xss

">`<style>.ask-title-cell-value input {background:black;color:white;}</style>`

This first line is just to demonstrate the XSS.

Related bug: [<marquee>XSS hole in timeline page</marquee> - comments are not HTML/XML escaped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76188/246052)

There seems to be unescaped HTML in the question suggestions. I noticed this when [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12272047/1256925) popped up in my suggestions, and all of a sudden the entire page turned red.

You can check this out by either putting "CSS3 selector for “not A and not B”?" as question title on non-meta SO, or "XSS security problems" on here (and then waiting for the suggestions to load). The "Questions that may already have your answer" box will then load any HTML in the question title, and on the first lines of the question's content (since that's loaded into the link's `title=""` attribute).

Demonstration picture:

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: Heh, using the title of this question as a test case brings both this question *and* the marquee one up, causing all sorts of fun...