# Do you have to be logged in to post a question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account)

do you have to be logged in to post a question?

Comment: No, you do not.

Comment: you obviously just did so

Answer (score 0):

No, but it makes it more simple for you to see the answers.

Comment: How does logging in help there?

Comment: If you ask more than a single question, you can see all of them in a single place. If you don't create an account, you will have to bookmark the URLs or search for them.

Comment: Unregistered members have full profile page, as far as I know the only thing they can't do is Vote..