# How SO manages and implements accountless questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account)

I was over in http://codereview.stackexchange.com and I noticed that I can post a question without registering or creating an account.

I have posted a question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com and noticed few cookies had been created. Also, I can edit the posted question.

[image]

I however, erased the cookies and revisited the question and I was not able to edit the question. I also cannot log in, although there is already a user created with the name I have entered.

So, just to confirm my suspicion
Now, the first and bottom ones expires after 6+ months.

Is this how SO determines?

Comment: Not *strictly* a duplicate, but I think you'll find all of your questions answered on the answer to the linked question.