# Merging accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I answered a question without creating an account I guess.
This account was somehow created for me.
https://stackexchange.com/users/778707/favone
Then I registered the name, but a new account was created.
So, can someone help me merge those two identities ?

https://stackexchange.com/users/778707/favone
and
https://stackexchange.com/users/2633826/favone

Thank you.

Comment: Well, I cannot login to both, as suggested. I can only log in to this one. The other one is virtual or something.

Comment: You'll have to provide *some* proof of 'ownership' of the other account. You'll have to talk to the SE team about that, there is nothing we can do here.

Comment: Anonymous accounts are cookie-based, see [Why should I register my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557). If you lost the cookie, merging it *may* be impossible if you cannot convince the team that the other account was indeed yours. They do have IP logs to verify claims.

Comment: judging by the userid's I would say those two accounts are created months, if not years apart. Visiting them proves my initial gut feeling., 778707 is created 2 years, 5 months ago