# Can Unregistered Users delete their questions?

Tags: support, unregistered-users

If I were to accidentally ask a question as an unregistered user, could I go back and delete that question?

Answer (score 3):

Not as an unregistered user. Unregistered accounts cannot delete posts, even their own.

But you can register your account and *then* delete, provided that the question:

- has no answers, or
- has one answer with no upvotes

See: [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account)

Comment: If it does not qualify for deletion on your own, you can always flag for moderators to delete it for you

Comment: Which they will decline without a convincing reason.