# Useless SE banner, visiting new communities

Tags: feature-request

Whenever I go exploring some Stack Exchange communities I didn't joined yet, the "Here's how it works" banners shows up, explaining me the general principle of Stack Exchange:

[image: Aviation Stack Exchange "How it works" Banner]

Most users visiting the community are probably from other Stack Exchange communities, thus already know the principle.
But even for other users, the provided informations are so basic that they are useless, provided they know any community based on the vote-up vote-down model. And yet, these informations are strongly emphasized on all Stack Exchange communities.

Please have this banner removed or explain me why I'm wrong.

Comment: Where is your data most visitors are from other SE sites?

Comment: Nowhere, I admit, I'm removing the claim (adding ...'probably from'...).

Comment: @loxaxs What is your evidence that most users are "probably" from other communities?

Comment: If you click the little black square in the top right it'll go away.

Comment: I agree that this banner is annoying once you already are familiar with SE. However, I think a better option would be to have the option to minimize it on all sites at once (instead of one at a time).

Comment: There is a significant amount of people who have thousands of reputation points after at Stackoverflow, who end up asking, horrible Superuser questions.  So the reason the banner is shown is to prevent that.  People familiar with how a StackExchange community works can still ask a bad question on a community they have not been a member of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Not everyone is familiar with the concept of voting questions/answers up and down. It's not complex, but it *isn't* automatic. Reddit is not the web.
- Not everyone is familiar with the idea of a *question and answer* site. Here Redditors and Slashdotters are as at sea as any forumite. And, in fact, the sheer persistence of posts calling SE a forum shows that this, at least, is absolutely essential, and probably underemphasized as is.
- The vast majority (well over 90%) of traffic on most SE sites is from users without even an unregistered account.
- The majority of new users signing up on e.g. ELL have no linked network account (or lack the association bonus). For example, [21 of the last 108 users to sign up on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers&sort=creationdate) ([2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?page=2&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate), [3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?page=3&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate)) have the +100 bonus, or less than 20%.

Comment: Your point 3. Are you saying most accounts **are** unregistered? refer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50684 Your point is unclear.

Comment: @NVZ: No, I said "without *even*" having an account that is not registered. Most accounts are registered, although certainly not all. (SE supports both types of accounts explicitly: one of them has an email address and password, or the equivalent through OpenID, the other is just a cookie.) But most site views are not associated with any account, even the ones without email registration.

Comment: @NVZ: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account for some explanation of the differences between account types.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying most visits are random people coming in from Google, that is, "most visitors don't have any account whatsoever".

Comment: @NVZ: Yes, that's correct.