# Alert users that they already gave anonymous feedback on a post

Tags: feature-request, post-feedback

Users without the "vote up" or "vote down" privilege can still click the upvote/downvote buttons. When doing so, they get such banners:

When upvoting without "vote up" privilege:

[image: upvote without enough rep banner]

When downvoting without "vote down" privilege:

[image: downvote without enough rep banner]

It is fine for the first time the user vote, however the user can keep clicking, even without reloading the page, and still get this message over and over again.

Instead, I suggest that after "voting" once, they will get message like:

> You already voted on this question

I know it's all about positive vibe but changing to a message like the above will give better impression.

Comment: I'm confused... your title doesn't seem to relate to the first two paragraphs of the question body. What is the message you're talking about and how does it relate to the anon feedback tool?

Comment: @Catija give me few minutes, I'll edit this into shape.

Comment: Oh. I understood. You want to change the message that appears for users with less than 15 reputation points into something that indicate you have already put a feedback, no?

Comment: @Catija done...

Answer (score 3):

Users with insufficient reputation to vote (<15 for up or <125 for down in most places) will get a message that their vote has been recorded but won't change the score of the post. This doesn't prevent the user from voting on the post later on when they have sufficient reputation to actually vote and it doesn't automatically count that vote once the user reaches the reputation necessary to cast real votes.

Saying simply "You already up-voted" or "You already down-voted" doesn't really make sense to me in this situation. Those votes *don't* count for anything that we actually use or reference on any sort of official basis. The user **has not** voted on the post. There is no indication on the user's profile that they've ever voted.

There *is* a place where the votes are stored in our database and we do keep them on a page for people with sufficient privileges to view, but that's not the same thing at all. What that mod is talking about is a 10k tool that allows anyone with the "access to moderator tools" to see posts with anonymous feedback. For users with that amount of rep, the page is found in the bottom of the "tools" section and has the url slug `/tools/post-feedback` - in fact, you have enough rep to view [this page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback?filter=week) (note, this is just one week, since the "all" tab can take a while to populate on SO).

It looks like this:

[image]

The other tabs at the top of the page "Overrated", "Underrated" highlight specific posts where users who voted anonymously voted very heavily in one direction or the other, even more than the actual tallied votes - so if a post has large numbers of downvotes and only a small amount of upvotes, it's "overrated" and if it has large numbers of upvotes and few downvotes, it's "underrated".

"Most helpful" and "least helpful" are lists of posts with the most anonymous upvotes and the most anonymous downvotes, respectively.

As you can see, though, these votes are all in groups, not by person voting or anything like that. As far as I'm aware, if a user who has insufficient reputation to vote votes on the same post more than once, those votes will actually be recorded more than once.

Comment: I agree the message "you already voted" isn't really ideal, but disagree that same user should be allowed to add more than one anon feedback record.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 These users are often not logged in, so we have no way to track who's casting the vote. I don't see any reason to change this, particularly since we don't use this internally for anything. It's mostly just "for fun" stats.

Comment: Maybe "You already gave feedback on this question/answer, when you will have 15/125 reputation you will be able to cast a vote"?

Comment: We do not know that someone gave feedback on a post! Does that make sense? We only tally that the feedback happened, not who gave it. This request is to change the message, not to change the behavior - there's no reason to change the message when it perfectly describes how things actually work now.

Comment: Ironically, anonymous visitors can't give anonymous feedback. [This is the banner they get when trying to vote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsN5a.png). Only logged in users, with not enough rep, can give "anonymous" feedback. Didn't know it's not recorded per-user, but it can easily (?) be recorded in a cookie, at least.

Comment: Interesting. We must still collect it, though... it doesn't make sense to have "Anonymous feedback" separate from "Registered feedback" otherwise. Though... ah, I bet I know the difference. "Anonymous feedback" is from unregistered profiles... so, someone created a profile but didn't actually register it. [They can't ever vote, even with sufficient reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account)... So the difference isn't "not logged in vs logged in" it's "registered account" vs "Unregistered account".