# Is it possible to set an avatar without using gravatar.com?

Tags: feature-request, profile-picture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we use non-gravatar avatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-use-non-gravatar-avatars)

I am trying to figure out how to use my own avatar with stackoverflow.com, I can't seem to find it. What gives? That shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Including an avatar even from a remote URL would be an easy addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that it is not possible, see : [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-use-non-gravatar-avatars)