# Gravatar gets a blue tinge effect after the Change Picture option is introduced

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, profile-page, design

Recently I saw StackOverflow introduced a new feature, `Change Picture`...

I've not changed my profile picture yet, it's still linked with my Gravatar account, but suddenly after introducing this feature, white color in my image went to mild blue(This happens randomly), I'll show you the difference..

I don't know why it is getting this blue tinge here

[image: Profile Picture With Blue Tinge]

Now am not that idiot, if you think that's a color of selection by mouse than you can see this

[image: Text and Image selected using mouse]

And what it should be(meta.stackoverflow.com Profile Picture)

[image: Real Image]

Comment: Your Gravatar has transparent areas and those seem to get coloured by whatever is below it.

Comment: @Bart It happens randomly, am using latest Firefox, I know IE6 is having issues with png's but this is Firefox..and if it has got color at the back than why not on meta?

Comment: It's the same for me in Chrome. So it's not just FF

Comment: @Bart haha see...

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Just click on `Change Picture` and see which color it is showing in background there? (e.g. [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IQMr5.png)).

Comment: Seriously? -1? If you think it's not a bug than shout here, this is a bug

Comment: @hims056 http://imgur.com/aL6zn it's white

Comment: Related: [Eeeek! Gravatar images now have a background color! Is this necessary?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101452/200500)

Comment: @Asad ya but I don't know why it gets random, and it happened to me from last 2 days..

Comment: The intermittent nature of this effect doesn't seem to be in keeping with the explanation given on the other question - re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular CSS for the div containing your Gravatar has a background-color of #E0EAF1 on Stack Overflow. This, combined with your transparent Gravatar will cause the colour effect you see.

[image]

On Meta it does not have the same make up  (resulting in a white background), so everything is as per usual there.

Comment: So why it gets random?

Comment: I wonder why it has that background-color. I would assume it would just be white.

Comment: And btw the correct `background-color` is `#E0EAF1`, used Firebug

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yep, copied the wrong value there.

Comment: @Asad I guess that is set dynamically, it comes it goes so am sure it's not the fixed one

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yeah, your image container gets a `gravatar-wrapper-128` class, whereas mine doesn't.

Comment: @Mr.Alien If this happens only occasionally (though it seems consistent to me) I don't have the answer. Out of my depth there.