# Avatar changed into my Facebook picture after adding Facebook to my account?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, gravatar, facebook

I've added Facebook to my accounts, and now Stack Overflow is displaying the photo from my Facebook profile instead of Gravatar.

Can I still have an option to use Gravatar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you log in to [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) using Facebook, we'll pull down your Facebook profile picture auto-magically.  Once connected, changes to your Facebook profile picture will be reflected on Stack Overflow

As your facebook.SO account and regular SO account are the same thing, changing the profile picture on either place reflects on both sites.

You can toggle back to Gravatar (and then back to Facebook, if you so desire), using the link underneath your avatar when editing your profile. When you turn the Facebook image off, it stays off. The trigger is the first login, basically.

[image: "use gravatar" option underneath display picture]

Switching back to Gravatar was going to be possible at launch, but then there's a minor earthquake on the east coast; held up that feature*.

Anyway, we've pushed it now.

<sub>*Technically, it kept me from `hg push`-ing it in time since I had to switch locales and machines.</sub>

Comment: It's much better now

Comment: Thanks! To be honest, I didn't check there. Then, a few minutes ago I realizes it may be in the *edit* page, and there it was... Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: So the avatar is defaulting to the Facebook image if FB is used for the primary login? (It doesn't affect me, but I wonder if folks like such new default while it has always been Gravatar up till now?)

Comment: @Arjan - if you login to Facebook.StackOverflow using Facebook, we'll pull down your facebook profile picture auto-magically.  When you turn it off, it stays off.  The trigger is login, basically.  The notion of a "primary login" is going away (which is not related to Facebook.SO).

Comment: Ok, very limited then, nice. Still then: is it documented somewhere, for those who are actually on facebook.se (maybe to ask questions about, say, *privacy*...)?

Comment: Is this pulled once, or does it also get updated when changed on Facebook?

Comment: @Arjan - it is currently pulled once due to a bug in facebook's graph API.  Once that's fixed, it will be synced with your facebook profile image.

Comment: @Kevin, sorry to bother you, but I'm not using FB myself so cannot test... After selecting Gravatar again, will logging in using Facebook pull the FB image again? And is the same avatar used on facebook.so and the regular SO? (And I've merged your comments into your answer; maybe we can remove our comments.)

Comment: @Arjan - no, it's a one time pull.  And yes, your facebook.so and so accounts are the same thing, changing the profile on picture either place reflects on both sites.

Comment: (Okay, I hope my edits summarize things correctly. Cheers!)