# Avatar from Google account?

Tags: feature-request, gravatar, profile-picture, google-plus, google-openid

I have figured out I must use GRAVATAR service when I want to change my avatar. However, I have read in [Avatar changed into my Facebook picture after adding Facebook to my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103734/avatar-changed-into-my-facebook-picture-after-adding-facebook-to-my-account) that Facebook avatars are pulled automatically. Is there any possibility to pull my avatar from Google account? I use my G-mail to log in to all Stack Exchange sites, and I have got avatar assigned there; it's my G+ avatar.

Is there the possibility? If there is this possibility, is any configuration or permission granting required?

Comment: This is all getting rather bizarre. If I book into a hotel room, the staff don't go pull all my light fittings from my house to fit them in said room (after I viewed the room without them and accepted.) I'd be irate if they did, naturally. Remind me _never_ to log in to Facebook.SO lest my personality be raped.

Comment: @MrDisappointment nothing unusual happens just by visiting fb.SO - that is purely limited to accounts directly linked through fb, and IIRC the use of the image is optional.

Comment: @Marc Not sure why, but recently haven't been getting notifications that strip the space+period from my username... on-topic, though, I read through Kevin's post in the linked answer which seems to indicate just by signing in to the Facebook.SO (_with_ a Facebook account) would automatically pull through your Facebook avatar. I didn't expect that behaviour when associating via Yahoo - and I'd be shocked if it had done so without asking: outraged, actually. I'm not sure for what reasons Facebook is so "special". Would it be OK for _any_ other service, or just ubiquitous networking ones?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment it relates to the swapover from the facebook developer forums to SO, allowing users of the existing forums to get sorted ASAP. Re yahoo - that is somewhat different. You aren't on yahoo.stackoverflow.com, etc... this was designed to help transfer users with the least disruption, inconvenience and support hassle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently supported; indeed, the facebook images were only very recently added (to [support facebook.stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)). It is an interesting possibility, but I'm not sure it is something that has an urgent priority - it is pretty easy to setup a gravatar, and that will support your identity on a wide range of sites. So much so that I am now actually surprised if I post anything *anywhere* and it **doesn't** immediately show my mug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll use gravatar then.

Answer (score 2):

This was implemented at some point several years ago, silently.

When someone creates new account using Google as the provider, Stack Exchange pulls their avatar from Google automatically.

For example, [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/611550/abdullah-al-mahin). ([avatar](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-LT-igsIzf_8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGo/xf1dohEmitE/photo.jpg?sz=328))