# Do not load Facebook-based avatars directly from the Facebook CDN

Tags: feature-request, profile-picture, privacy, facebook

Users who register for their account via Facebook get [their Facebook profile photo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103734/avatar-changed-into-my-facebook-picture-after-adding-facebook-to-my-account/103753#103753) as their default avatar. However, the avatar is not copied to SE servers or Imgur, and thus the original URL is kept. This URL compromises the privacy of the user as it contains their Facebook user ID which everyone can easily extract and then view the profile.

The image is also not visible at all to those who have Facebook blocked for their own privacy (by extensions such as Ghostery or browser features [like Firefox's Tracking Protection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316284/facebook-derived-profile-images-are-not-displayed-in-firefox-when-tracking-prote)), or due to network policy (e.g. some work and school networks block Facebook).

With the new avatar system, it would be much better if the Facebook photo was stored like a manually uploaded avatar to avoid this problem.

Comment: Related: [Privacy and policy issues exposing Facebook User IDs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107542)

Comment: @fred if it happens for twitter as well, better mention here too. :)

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow lets Facebook track us across their sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384864/stack-overflow-lets-facebook-track-us-across-their-sites)

Comment: Yeah, I don't care so much about the tracking part but rather about the fact that now with tracking protection in firefox the avatars don't load...

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog The question you linked to, despite its title, also includes "tracking protection prevents the images from loading" in the third-to-last paragraph. It's a duplicate regardless.

Comment: I don't want my profile picture to come under creative commons though. I want it to be owned by me with no sharing.