# Facebook-derived profile images are not displayed in Firefox when tracking protection is enabled

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-picture

[Thanks to KacosPro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316284/some-members-pictures-are-not-displayed-with-linux-but-they-are-with-windows/316321#316321), we've identified the cause: Firefox's new Tracking Protection blocks these images:

[image: screenshot showing tracking protection enabled in Firefox along with niels nielsen's profile (and blocked image)]

---

Some member's picture displays as a white square instead of real picture. For example there https://physics.stackexchange.com/users, the user niels nelsen shows as a white square, but not on Windows. When I click on his profile, something even stranger happens, the top half of his picture is grey, the bottom half is white.

The exact same bug happens for some members only. Let me provide a few of them: https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/40292/niels-nielsen, https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/132371/%c3%81rp%c3%a1d-szendrei, https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/68181/time4tea, and https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/176409/snoob-dogg.

Happy debugging!

Edit: Apparently some people believe(d) the ISP was blocking "graph.facebook.com", or something like that. A ping test as well as connections using a browser to graph.facebook.com, fbcdn.net and [this link](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/12274599_10153361104922753_8506421902362546952_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&oh=966b47aabf207946b259a943ead9dc1e&oe=5C19B157) seem to point out that the domain is in fact not blocked. Thus, to me, the mystery is still not elucidated.

Adding a picture of the whole thing. [image: bug]

Comment: No repro for me on Mac. These images are all from Facebook. Are you blocking Facebook?

Comment: Not really. I tried on Firefox (with some blockers that I just disabled, but that didn't help), also with Tor Browser. Same problem in both browsers.

Comment: Can you check the console/network tabs in dev tools? Any errors?

Comment: You appear to have graph.facebook.com blocked so the pictures aren't able to load. Nothing we can really do about that.

Comment: @animuson well, SE can upload the pictures to the dedicated imgur host. This way everyone would only have to make sure one single domain is whitelisted to see **all** profile pictures.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That... doesn't make any sense at all. The point of linking directly to an external source is so that if the user updates it wherever they're pulling from, it updates here too. It's the same premise as using Gravatar. Saving everything to Imgur completely disallows users from utilizing that functionality.

Comment: I'm on Linux, and I can see neils picture correctly

Comment: @DarkCygnus it got nothing to do with browser or OS. The block is network level, e.g. blocked by companies who don't want their employees to use Facebook while working, so they just block the whole domain.

Comment: @animuson Not sure why you think I have graph.facebook.com blocked. Disabling all addons on Firefox doesn't fix the issue, and typing "ping graph.facebook.com" in a terminal shows that it is not blocked whatsoever.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is there a conclusive test I can do to check whether it is blocked in my networks? Because typing "ping graph.facebook.com" does not give any such clue, it just transmits packets without any packet loss.

Comment: Ping isn't reliable way, you need to test via a browser, or software simulating browser request. SE doesn't have such tools.

Comment: It's as simple as just browsing to https://graph.facebook.com. What do you see when visiting the link?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I get an error: "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api".

Comment: Oh, OK. Next step: browse to https://fbcdn.net and let us know what happens. (that is the actual domain used to host Facebook pictures. Normally, when not blocked, you should be redirected to facebook.com)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am indeed redirected to facebook.com, with the sign up page.

Comment: So, final test: browse to https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/12274599_10153361104922753_8506421902362546952_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&oh=966b47aabf207946b259a943ead9dc1e&oe=5C19B157 and let us know what you see?

Comment: @ShadowWizard A man with hat with a guitar.

Comment: And you still don't see it [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/40292/niels-nielsen)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Right. Half of top is grey, bottom half is white.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Which browser did you use?

Comment: Please take a screenshot and add it to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1254/discussion-between-shadow-wizard-and-coniferous-smellerulpbg-w8zgjr).

Comment: Used to happen for me with the same list of users plus [this guy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/179151/aaron-stevens) on Physics. It would reappear when I signed out of my account (same browser, but a private window). A week back, the pictures started showing up again. I was on Brave 0.24.0 for Windows 10. I didn't change anything, and I don't think I'm blocking any websites.

Comment: It's because of [Firefox tracking protection](https://www.mozilla.org/es-MX/firefox/61.0.1/tracking-protection/start/?step=3). It happens for me always on macOS too. [When the shield appears on the url bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tmDQ.png) is because it blocked some parts of the page

Comment: For me, many of the profile pictures are missing indeed, but Niels Nielsen’s for one shows up correctly. This suggests there is a random element to the problem, possibly a caching issue somewhere down the line (but clearing the browser cache didn’t have any effect, so it’s more subtle than that).

Comment: ... And now that I’ve restarted my browser, it all works correctly.

Comment: @KacosPro Spot on! That was it... Could you please post it as answer?

Comment: @coniferous_smellerULPBG-W8ZgjR FF

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/allowing-images-from-external-sources-opens-doors-to-serious-security-exploits/279664#279664

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of [Firefox Tracking Protection](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/62.0.0/tracking-protection/start/?step=3), as far as I know it will happen on all OS, it happens for me on macOS too.

[image: Image showing Firefox tracking protection on action]

When this shield appears on the url bar is because it blocked some parts of the page

Comment: Mozilla showing us the error of our ways.

Comment: @Guest Mozilla should show an indication in the replacement picture that it was blocked. Now I clicked tooling support, got shown an image which wasn't blocked (!) and had to browse the internet and ask other mods what the heck was going on.