# What is the role of graph.facebook.com here and why should it be loaded?

Tags: support, facebook

I just realized that Stack Exchange websites becomes a bit slow and accidentally I saw `"Waiting for graph.facebook.com ..."` in the loading massage box in the bottom of the browser. What is the role of this link here and why should it be loaded?

I am asking this because `facebook.com` is banned in my country by default and any webpage that uses its contents will be slow or half-loaded.

So is this the reason of Stack Exchange being slow for me? What other sub websites are loaded when I open `math.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: I don't really know what that is but this seems very relevant: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/

Comment: Or related to users registering with their facebook accounts

Comment: Also see the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: my account is registered with Gmail.

Comment: A workaround for the slowness is it add `127.0.0.1    graph.facebook.com` to the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). It is file `/etc/hosts` on Linux and `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows.

Comment: It can be supplemented with `127.0.0.1 static.ak.facebook.com`, `127.0.0.1 badge.facebook.com`, `127.0.0.1 facebook.com`, `127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com`, and `127.0.0.1 connect.facebook.net`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are from users' avatars, taken directly from Facebook.

When a user logs in using Facebook, Stack Exchange is taking their profile picture from Facebook, as-is.

I agree it's terrible and would really like to have the picture imported to Imgur. The downside is that when the users change their Facebook picture it won't be synched with their Stack Exchange profiles, but that's not a Stack Exchange problem.

Comment: Maybe we need to pay these poor folks over at Facebook some money so they can buy a bigger server?

Comment: @rene using Facebook Pay, of course.

Comment: Another reason for not taking images directly from Facebook is that they then do not work in Firefox due to tracking protection (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316284). Which, incidentally, gives the OP a workaround: switch to Firefox, it won’t attempt to load the images in the first place, solving the slow-down issue.