# Default profile picture from Facebook is being displayed, instead of my actual Facebook picture

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture, facebook

I noticed my profile picture on the SE sites is displayed as the default Facebook avatar, even though I do have a profile picture on Facebook which used to be displayed on Stack Exchange until yesterday.

Examples:

> [image]

> [image]

I assume it is a bug either from Facebook or from the profile picture fetching  algorithm.

Comment: @Ollie btw, do we have evidence that the aforementioned feature-request has been implemented? Intentionally or not intentionally?

Comment: @AntonMenshov Given that there are still bug reports being made, I'd say not.

Comment: The image is loaded from: https://scontent.fyvr3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.30497-1/c59.0.200.200a/p200x200/84628273_176159830277856_972693363922829312_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&ccb=2&_nc_sid=12b3be&_nc_ohc=OtdmIKfFFJsAX_GUKkU&_nc_ht=scontent.fyvr3-1.fna&tp=27&oh=4a7a1cff267956267940673bf46caad9&oe=5FBB97B9 - his real avatar should be: https://scontent.fyvr3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/65765828_2413723418689599_963970139315765248_o.jpg?_nc_cat=109&ccb=2&_nc_sid=85a577&_nc_ohc=Lt0yrSSGVBQAX_bmVyj&_nc_ht=scontent.fyvr3-1.fna&oh=3031271613996684738158d625743a9c&oe=5FBC7428

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164325/do-not-load-facebook-based-avatars-directly-from-the-facebook-cdn . It rather appears to be a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355805/default-profile-picture-from-facebook-is-being-displayed-instead-of-facebook-pi (which was, however, posted later than the question here).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek true. Fixed. (The duplicate closure, not the bug. ;))