# Profile picture rendering bug

Tags: bug, profile-picture

If a user does not upload a profile image (or perhaps something else is causing it), you get this:

[image: image not found icon instead of a profile picture in the question list]

Comment: This isn't caused by the user not uploading a profile picture (in that case, you just get an identicon). It's caused by SE being [unable to access the picture](https://graph.facebook.com/1562212813789444/picture?type=large) that's been uploaded, likely because it comes from facebook (to repro, right click [their profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8059748/jschmitter) and open in a separate tab)

Comment: It is not a bug. The user was using a profile picture from Facebook that is now broken (they possibly disabled their Facebook profile, but could be other reasons). The only thing we could do is [stop using direct Facebook links altogether](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164325/do-not-load-facebook-based-avatars-directly-from-the-facebook-cdn).

Comment: The *handling* of these broken image cases could be much better, but it's not exactly a bug if the image breaks externally in a way not caused by nor controllable by Stack Exchange.

Comment: Can't you create validation for this, that if an image at that URL uploads correct (status 200) you show it, and if not, upload some default image, or nothing at all?

Comment: In theory they could ofcourse. But there are plenty of other pressing issues to solve besides this one, which is most likely user induced. As the person changed their privacy settings, or deleted their facebook altogether. It is also something the user itself could fix.

Comment: Facebook images are not *uploaded*. They are directly linked *from* Facebook. So validating the upload does nothing. If the image works initially that doesn't mean that the link will continue working in the future. That's how Facebook images are - there are external factors that can make them unavailable and it's not something that is easily detectable as a one-off check. As mentioned, changing the privacy settings or deleting the account makes that image unavailable. Perhaps if the user changed the privacy settings, they can change them back to show the image, too.