# Is there a way to switch from using Gravatar to using Facebook from our SE avatar?

Tags: support, profile-page, gravatar, facebook, profile-picture

I can only find info on how to go from Facebook to Gravatar but not the other way.  Maybe I'm the only fool that would want to do this? :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to use your Facebook picture instead of the one provided by Gravatar?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly correct.

Answer (score 2):

The avatar shown in Stack Exchange site is the one you have on gravatar.com, if there is one that matches the email address you have associated with your account. There isn't an option that allows you to decide which avatar you want to use on your Stack Exchange account.

If you log in to facebook.stackoverflow.com using Facebook, facebook.stackoverflow.com and Stack Overflow will use the picture set in your Facebook profile.

The other method is to create another gravatar from your Facebook picture, and associate it with an email address that you use in your Stack Exchange accounts. As some email providers allow you to use email addresses such as your.email-meta@your.provider.com, which will send the messages to your.email@your.provider.com, you can associate the new gravatar to a similar addy, and you would get email from Stack Exchange at the usual email address.

Comment: If a user first logs into SE on the facebook.stackoverflow.com site their facebook profile pic is used and the rest of the SE network will use it for your Avatar.  From the top answer on this question...http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar
"Or, when using your Facebook account to log into facebook.stackoverflow.com, the image is pulled from your Facebook profile picture, and also used on the regular stackoverflow.com website."

Answer (score 2):

If you login to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com, your Facebook profile picture will automatically pulled into your Stack Exchange account as per [this post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103753/163863).

To copy this change to all your Stack Exchange accounts, try clicking "Save and  Copy Profile to all Stack Exchange Accounts" at the bottom of the "Edit Profile" page on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com

Comment: OK, I went to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com and logged out.  Then I logged back in using my facebook account.  The site pulled in my facebook profile pic.  Then I logged out of meta.stackoverflow.com and logged back in using the facebook OpenID.  meta still uses my Gravatar.  Going to the Edit profile area and clicking "Change Picture" simply redirects to gravatar.com.  It appears the only way to use facebook profile pictures throught the SE network is if your very first registration was done on facebook.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @GollyJer: see my additional paragraph (you may need to copy the change to all Stack Exchange accounts).

Comment: Getting closer. :-)  That worked to copy it to stackoverflow.com, but it didn't get pushed to any of my other accounts.  I'll wait a few minutes and see if it's a caching issue.

Comment: I waited 24 hours, since the text below profile pics said it could take that long, and it still didn't get pushed to other profiles.  I now have another question as to whether this is a bug or mislabeled button.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125197/clicking-the-save-and-copy-profile-to-all-stack-exchange-accounts-doesnt-work