# Clicking the 'Save and Copy Profile to all Stack Exchange Accounts' doesn't work from facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, user-interface, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

I'm attempting to use my Facebook profile pic for my SE accounts.  [It seems like it should be possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125021/is-there-a-way-to-switch-from-using-gravatar-to-using-facebook-from-our-se-avata/125023) but after a little trial and error I think I've found a bug.

After using Facebook to log into facebook.stackoverflow.com my Facebook profile pic was successfully pulled into the account.  However, after clicking "Save and Copy Profile to all Stack Exchange Accounts" and waiting over 24 hours, the profile pic is not transferred to any other SE account.

Is this is a bug or the expected behavior of a mislabeled button?

Comment: Your profile was copied, everything *except* the facebook profile picture.  I'm pretty sure this is by-design as it's only supported on SO (the other sites haven't been styled with it in mind), but I've asked to make certain.

Comment: I'm sure it's by design, although the button should be relabeled, and pretty sure it's such low priority that it won't get changed.

Comment: I'll take a look Monday, we'll probably make this copy the profile picture everywhere, as that's less confusing behavior.

Comment: That would be awesome.  Thanks Nick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, it's by design.
When you log in on facebook.stackoverflow.com using your Facebook login, the picture you use in your Facebook account is transferred to your account on facebook.stackoverflow.com; as facebook.stackoverflow.com is just a mini-site of Stack Overflow, the same image is used on Stack Overflow. The image is not transferred to other Stack Exchange sites, because the other sites just use the Gravatar image associated with the email associated with your Stack Exchange accounts.

It is just facebook.stackoverflow.com that handles Facebook in a different way; in fact it's the only site that has a Facebook login button.

[image: screenshot]

The other sites allow you to login using Facebook as OpenID provider.

[image: screenshot]