# Is there a way to set your profile picture to something other than a Gravatar?

Tags: support, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we use non-gravatar avatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-use-non-gravatar-avatars)

Question's all in the title. I want to set the picture to a picture I have on my hard drive. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Answer is **No**. Gravatar is the only way to set your profile image. The other way of setting profile image is if you login via Facebook, your profile picture will be pulled as your avatar here ( Source from Yannis Rizos's [Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145376/is-there-a-way-to-set-your-profile-picture-to-something-other-than-a-gravatar/145377#comment415268_145377). )

Comment: Damn...I think that's very unfair. As a show of defiance, I'll keep my current picture :)

Comment: I _think_ that if you login via Facebook, your profile picture will be pulled as your avatar here (but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: that can be an additional information, i will try it and update my answer if it happens, Thanks

Comment: @YannisRizos This seems to be correct. It is stated at various places here on Meta. In [this answer for example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103753/161198).