# Facebook partnership and subsite no more?

Tags: support, facebook.stackoverflow

I noticed today when going to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com I am 301 Moved Permanently redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook*. Is the mini-site gone or is this just a bug?

Comment: Aak, you put the actual link I need to test in a code-block, and the reference text as the link. All that copying and pasting I have to do!!

Comment: @JonW I have no idea what you are talking about... ;)

Comment: Are the upvotes out of shared curiosity, or is this the community rejoicing? :)

Comment: @Bart no, the upvotes on the answer are the community rejoicing :-)

Comment: a sad day indeed ;)

Comment: [Ding-Dong! The Witch is Dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ding-Dong!_The_Witch_Is_Dead)

Comment: Three cheers! I have several tags that I filter on in the close votes review queue every day. The Facebook questions are always... interesting.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

We have removed the subsite.  I am in the process of removing code for all subsites (it was the only instance in production) to greatly simplify many areas of our codebase.

facebook.stackoverflow.com was always an experiment, one we hoped would work out - but it didn't.  The quality on the facebook tags didn't improve as a result of its presence, and the technical tradeoffs to support it were quite great. It causes a great deal of load on our systems when specific pages are hit because there's just no low-cost way to "filter" the site down to facebook-only tags.

After we weighed everything, it just wasn't worth keeping - it wasn't helping, caused confusion and it was causing technical hurt.  I won't even go into the calls we get at the office from people locked out of their facebook accounts.

Comment: BoltClock likes this.

Comment: "I won't even go into the calls we get at the office from people locked out of their facebook accounts." Please do. Make a podcast out of them.

Comment: LoL please, please, please, do what @Yannis suggested. I could use a good laugh!

Comment: @Nick Is it possible to know whether the off-topic questions were coming from google hits or developers.facebook.com. Until that is known I doubt it will stop the influx

Comment: @Nick: are Facebook and Stack Overflow still in a relationship then, or is Stack Overflow changing their status to "single"?

Comment: @Matt, it's complicated.

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote the above 2 comments or to flag them... Why isn't there a dislike button?

Comment: You going to let these folks know about this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/ ?

Comment: @BradLarson they were alerted a few weeks ago

Comment: The nightmare is over!

Comment: Holy crap... [we did live through it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/wont)

Comment: @Won't: So you're taking everyone to Vegas then?

Comment: @animuson: No, SE is. For putting us all through this nightmare in the first place.

Comment: Just curious: when folks once logged in using Facebook on that minisite, are their profile pictures still synchronized between SE and FB today? (Like [explained in this August 2011 post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103734/avatar-changed-into-my-facebook-picture-after-adding-facebook-to-my-account/103753#103753).)

Comment: @Arjan yes, since the link is to their current picture Url provided by  FB