# facebook and facebook.stackoverflow tags

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, meta

I understand that the *[facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) tag* is for all *facebook* related questions on StackOverflow and Meta.

Now what is the point of tagging [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202434/how-come-this-question-is-being-closed-as-off-topic/) with the [facebook.stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/facebook.stackoverflow) tag?

It does not specifically talk about the *http://facebook.stackoverflow.com* site, doesn't report a problem or bug, doesn't mention the site within its context.

Does it mean the question is mistagged? If not, I am thinking why isn't every question tagged [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) not tagged [facebook.stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/facebook.stackoverflow).

It's kind of a circular reference and we don't want to see every *facebook* question also tagged *facebook.stackoverflow*, or do we?

Comment: Your question doesn't need the `facebook.stackoverflow.com` tag either. :-P

Comment: you're right @MartijnPieters that's ironic reporting a mistagged question while mistagging my own haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There **used** to be a dedicated site for Facebook tags only, under an agreement between Stack Exchange and Facebook, the company.

The [agreement ended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186850/facebook-partnership-and-subsite-no-more) after 2 years and the dedicated 'view' site http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ now redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook* instead.

So, your answer there, stating *There is no relation between the two*, is not true, from a historical point of view.

That said, the question asker must've assumed that because the tag exists (found when autocompleting 'facebook'), that the tag must apply. It does not apply to that question and I've removed it.