# Changing profile picture

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we use non-gravatar avatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-use-non-gravatar-avatars)

Changing your profile picture is a hassle on Stack Overflow.
It redirects to Gravatar.

Can't it be implemented like on Facebook or Google+, in much easier way?

Comment: This was asked for a long time ago in [Can we use non-gravatar avatars?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-use-non-gravatar-avatars) and it's still [meta-tag:status-deferred]. The only alternative that's been added is Facebook profile pictures for users using Facebook accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most ideal solution but better than nothing.  You could specify different [email address tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) to your email address to effectively give you different hashes (and therefore different avatars).  Of course this assumes your email provider supports this.  No need to register a different email address at gravatar, you can just use one.

I do something like this:

My primary gravatar email: `my.email@example.com`
My [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) email: `my.email+so@example.com`
My [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8995/jeff-mercado) email: `my.email+gaming@example.com`

etc.

Then just attach the desired avatars for each and register those emails for the sites.  i.e., Set my Stack Overflow email to: `my.email+so@example.com`, Gaming.SE to `my.email+gaming@example.com`, etc.