# Why am I forced to use Gravatar for my profile avatar?

Tags: discussion, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we use non-gravatar avatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-use-non-gravatar-avatars)

Why am I being forced to use [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) when I want to upload an avatar to my profile?

Is it possible to just upload an avatar image directly to my profile without creating a Gravatar account?

Comment: yes please migrate. I saw a mention of that in the stackoverflow.com tag but, wasn't sure how to post there.

Comment: The "why" is answered in detail in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/gravatars-identicons-and-you/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to upload avatars to your profile directly, without going though Gravatar.

Comment: Part of the question, I believe is "*why*?". (I don't know the answer myself...)